# Can I execute didSelectRowAtIndexPath only for specific cell identifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using two different custom table cells in my table view. That said, I only want didSelectRowAtIndexPath to fire when, for example, Custom Cell Identifier 2 is tapped (but not when Custom Cell Identifer 1 is tapped). How might I go about this? See code below. Right now, didSelectRowAtIndexPath fires when either cell is tapped...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


   static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";
   static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";


    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName: ChatTableIdentifier bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: ChatTableIdentifier];

    UINib *nib2 = [UINib nibWithNibName: ChatTableIdentifier2 bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib2 forCellReuseIdentifier: ChatTableIdentifier2];

}
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSDictionary *data = self.messages[indexPath.row];

        id swaptime = data[@"swaptime"];
        if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

            static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";

            SwapDetailTableViewCell *cell = (SwapDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSString *time = data[@"swaptime"];
            cell.startTime.text = time;

            NSString *timeEnd = data[@"endswaptime"];
            cell.endTime.text = timeEnd;

            return cell;
        } else {
            static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";

            ChatTableViewCell *cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSString *userName = data[@"name"];
            cell.sendingUser.text = userName;

            NSString *messageBody = data[@"body"];
            cell.messageDisplayed.text = messageBody;

            NSString *timeReceived = data[@"published at"];
            cell.timeStamp.text = timeReceived;

            return cell;
        }
    }


        -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


            SwapDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[SwapDetailsViewController alloc]
                                                                initWithNibName:@"SwapDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

            detailViewController.swapDetails = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

          [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an if condition inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as the one you put in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        NSDictionary *data = self.messages[indexPath.row];

        id swaptime = data[@"swaptime"];

        //perform action based on this, and don't do anything in second case

        if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])   

        //this indexPath will always contain cell of one kind

        }else{

         // this indexPath will contain second cell kind
        }
    }
```

Or alternatively you can also do-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       // this will give you cell at the selected indexPath
       id cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]

       //perform action based on this, and don't do anything in second case
       if ([cell isKindOfClass:[SwapDetailTableViewCell class]])                    

       }else{

       }
}
```

Comment: While this works, it suffers a maintenance issue. You have now duplicated the logic in two places - here and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If the logic ever changes, you have to update identical code in two places.

Comment: That is true, i added an alternate logic that should solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a particular row to be selected, the proper solution is to implement the `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method and return `nil` for rows you don't want selected.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (some condition) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return indexPath;
    }
}
```

So now you need to determine the proper condition. I can think of three ways in your case:

1. Use the same `if` condition you have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
2. Get the row's cell and look at the cell's class.
3. Get the row's cell and look at the cell's reuse identifier.

Option 1 isn't ideal because if you change the logic in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have to remember to change it here too. Options 2 and 3 are essentially the same in this case. I'd go with option 3.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString: ChatTableIdentifier) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return indexPath;
    }
}
```

Since you are now using `ChatTableIdentifier` in three places, I would move the lines:

```
static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";
static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";
```

to before the `@implementation` line and remove them from everywhere else in the file. No sense in recreating the same variables over and over.

Answer (score 0):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can call method

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for the indexPath of a current row and get the cell you are currently selecting. Every cell has a reuse identifier, so you can check the identifier of the cell you are selecting. if it equals "SwapDetailTableViewCell", then you can perform everything you need(for example move to another viewController)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([cell.reuseIdentifier  isEqual: @"SwapDetailTableViewCell"]) {
    SwapDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[SwapDetailsViewController alloc]
                                                       initWithNibName:@"SwapDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.swapDetails = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense - can you show me what the code for that would look like? I get the overall logic of your explanation, but I'm lost/confused re: what the syntax looks like?

Comment: No, do not do this. Never call the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method yourself.

Comment: @rmaddy could you please suggest your own solution for me to know how to deal with such problems